# codeigniter: login using email but I need username in session

Tags: codeigniter, session

After I created a registration form with the fields: user, email, pass, cpass, I saved the user field in a session, so when I submit the form it should redirect me to the  homepage displaying the message: `hello + $this->session->userdata('user')`.

In my login form I have only the fields: email, pass and I want after submitting the form to be redirected aswell to my homepage displaying the same message but I don't know how to save the username in the session.How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have a database where you're storing user info? You should be matching against that to login, and if their credentials are valid, add them to the session from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have a function in your model claass for checking user credentials.like-

```
     function check_user($email, $pass) {
     //select db column that you will need for future task
            $this->db->select('id, user, email, pass);
            $this->db->from('user_table');
            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $this->db->where('pass', $pass);
            $this->db->limit(1);

            $query = $this->db->get();

            if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
                return $query->result();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

after returning in your controller function just put them in the session.like-

```
       public function do_login(){

         $result = $this->login_model->check_user($email, $pass);
         //put them in the session
             foreach($result as $row){  
                $this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $row->id);                            
                $this->session->set_userdata('user', $row->user);                          
                $this->session->set_userdata('email', $row->email);
                //put more information as your need                              
               }
        }
```

please modify the code as your situation.